# Множество поддоменов и сессии codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Есть сайт с множеством поддоменов, т.е. вида moskva.site.ru, piter.site.ru, kazan.site.ru  и т.д.

Использую codeigniter 3 и его родной механизм сессий (с хранением в бд).

При этом, если авторизация происходит на одном поддомене, то при переходе на другой поддомен приходится авторизовываться заново. Как это исправить?

Т.е. хочу чтобы авторизация происходила в рамках всего сайта, а не отдельного поддомена.

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось очень простым:

В файле конфигурации '/application/config/config.php' нужно просто изменить значение опции:

$config['cookie_domain'] = 'site.ru';

где site.ru - наш сайт